# Can Each Real symmetric n×n Matrix be Obtained By squaring another real n×n symmetric matrix.??

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

For any Real symmetric n×n matrix. Can it be Obtained By squaring another real symmetric matrix.??

I.e For each real symmetric Matrix A does there exist Another real symmetric matrix B
Such that B^2 = A.??
I think it should be no Because if A has negative eigenvalues then B^2 can never have negative eigenvalues .

But what about odd power ?? Can There exist B such that B^3  = A

If Yes can you prove For ANY real SQUARE matrix X there exist real symmetric  M such that M^2 = X^t.X.    (X^t = X transpose)
Since here X^tX has always positive eigenvalues what about this case

Comment: First conjecture is false, second conjecture is true.

Comment: A set of eigenvectors for $A$ will always be a set of eigenvectors for $A^2$. If $A$ is symmetric it is diagonalisable with real eigenvalues, hence $A^2$ is diagonalisable with nonnegative eigenvalues, while $A^3$ has real eigenvalues.

Comment: If $A=B^2$, then $A=B^TB$ and it must be positive semidefinite.